# Is Lazy<T> supported in the compact framework?

Tags: .net, compact-framework, .net-4.0

Does anyone know if the new [lazy initialization class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(VS.100).aspx) (`Lazy<T>`) is or will be supported in the compact framework? I've looked on MSDN, but the support stuff listed on the bottom is kind of cryptic when it comes to support for the compact framework vs. the full-blown .Net framework.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not as of yet.  As far as I Know, the latest release of the compact framework CLR is 2.0.  The `Lazy<T>` type wasn't introduced until 4.0 of the full CLR and hence the earliest version it could appear in the compact framework is also 4.0.

Comment: There was a 3.5 version of the compact framework available as of January 2008: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=e3821449-3c6b-42f1-9fd9-0041345b3385

Comment: @Jason, I was attempting to refer to the associated CLR version.  I updated my answer to be a bit clearer.

Comment: Ah I see. Looking at Wikipedia there is the following quote (referencing the .Net framework, not the compact framework... but the same would apply to both):

"As with .NET Framework 3.0, version 3.5 uses the CLR of version 2.0. Which means it's not a complete new framework, but just an extension of 2.0, and it can't run without it."